# How to capture query string using Elastic Apm python agent?

Tags: apm, elastic-apm

APM Python Agent can capture request body (e.g. POST variables) by enabling [`CAPTURE_BODY`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/python/current/configuration.html#config-capture-body) variable.

How can i capture query string (e.g. GET Parameters) ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be captured in the metadata under "url":

[image: https://capture.dropbox.com/5fZqpiFkgN1Vr9lS]

If it's not, you should open an [issue](https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-python/issues/new/choose). Note that `url.query` will only show if it's non-empty.

**Edit:**

We don't store the query params separately, so if you want to query/aggregate against specific query params you'll need to add them manually with our [api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/python/current/api.html):

- [`elasticapm.label`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/python/current/api.html#api-label)
- [`elasticapm.set_custom_context`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/python/current/api.html#api-set-custom-context)

Comment: it did capture `url.query`.  what i wanted to do is to perform an aggregate query over query string. `url.query` store full query string as text, so i can not perform any term/aggregate query over individual query parameter.